# R aggregate error

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm trying to `aggregate` the following table:

```
> str(Denom_2008_A)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  37 variables:
 $ DEPT: chr  "75" "77" "78" "91" ...
 $ 16  : num  9771 9090 9405 7871 682 ...
 $ 17  : num  9659 8780 9472 7886 787 ...
 $ 18  : num  9980 9092 9226 8116 696 ...
 $ 19  : num  12274 8306 8684 8015 738 ...
 $ 20  : num  13964 8836 8799 7245 781 ...
 $ 21  : num  15793 8477 8288 7366 753 ...
 $ 22  : num  17263 8270 8152 7373 824 ...
 $ 23  : num  18853 8588 7945 7183 821 ...
 $ 24  : num  20793 8352 8603 7648 734 ...
 $ 25  : num  22133 8674 8700 7501 962 ...
 $ 26  : num  23840 8603 8819 7751 921 ...
 $ 27  : num  23746 8560 8773 7855 895 ...
 $ 28  : num  23570 8667 9131 7774 1053 ...
 $ 29  : num  22457 8461 9150 7967 1163 ...
 $ 30  : num  21762 8832 9142 8361 1172 ...
 $ 31  : num  20639 8665 8822 7842 1021 ...
 $ 32  : num  20549 8796 9110 8058 999 ...
 $ 33  : num  19581 8980 9706 8176 983 ...
 $ 34  : num  19087 9486 9545 8395 1109 ...
 $ 35  : num  18745 9812 10316 8809 986 ...
 $ 36  : num  18277 10122 10208 8852 1111 ...
 $ 37  : num  17702 10244 10458 8845 1086 ...
 $ 38  : num  17072 10328 10388 9182 1080 ...
 $ 39  : num  16173 9991 10287 9083 941 ...
 $ 40  : num  16179 10186 10250 9034 924 ...
 $ 41  : num  15925 10161 10509 9139 923 ...
 $ 42  : num  15906 10096 10477 9164 1109 ...
 $ 43  : num  15392 9868 10682 9306 1078 ...
 $ 44  : num  15565 9803 11179 9242 915 ...
 $ 45  : num  14906 9986 10711 8995 1048 ...
 $ 46  : num  15054 9788 10743 9072 984 ...
 $ 47  : num  14834 9359 10364 9319 1029 ...
 $ 48  : num  14603 9302 10285 8755 1004 ...
 $ 49  : num  14262 9492 10483 8104 922 ...
 $ 50  : num  14160 9239 9984 8670 801 ...
 $ 51  : num  14109 9297 10215 8066 928 ...
```

Using the following command,

```
Denom_2008_A<-aggregate(.~DEPT, data=Denom_2008_A, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

returns this error message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind(16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'DEPT')
```

What is the problem ? Here is the data:

```
dput(Denom_2008_A)
structure(list(DEPT = c("75", "77", "78", "91", "92", "92", "93", 
"94", "95"), `16` = c(9770.86233333519, 9090.45619927748, 9404.82617208335, 
7871.24477766893, 681.562913267321, 7624.6417197496, 9734.09147183233, 
7479.21227575844, 8156.19123409508), `17` = c(9659.33101413589, 
8780.13190720995, 9471.76825710053, 7885.5226747048, 786.854151059239, 
7753.87252708308, 9884.2991895958, 7765.70470478036, 8149.90658515781
), `18` = c(9979.96186454912, 9092.32492775475, 9226.1058374391, 
8116.46883300314, 696.156281844465, 7945.40155695269, 10138.187090902, 
7738.35414539946, 8092.82244551196), `19` = c(12274.0409046468, 
8306.42116530583, 8684.22019307588, 8015.26740000408, 738.010258028334, 
7891.54870247486, 10112.173310227, 8067.23738786945, 8183.24205745055
), `20` = c(13963.9846397417, 8836.41666678529, 8798.74633702351, 
7244.69933889342, 781.102966189844, 7752.26168622556, 10071.3068629951, 
8584.07771780541, 8086.3933326287), `21` = c(15793.3677060353, 
8476.88078359514, 8287.78905655766, 7366.11697091733, 752.987358313531, 
7942.47158218605, 10585.7740579806, 8422.164598846, 7890.15037423227
), `22` = c(17262.8915320195, 8269.719645753, 8151.7638685453, 
7372.81024888355, 824.011288213469, 8623.00575394401, 10887.7649618604, 
8529.77669382989, 8066.36791466219), `23` = c(18853.1022102185, 
8587.78067777459, 7945.19131785005, 7182.64457125645, 820.552754630716, 
9286.19980042841, 10836.4036316187, 8759.60381322597, 8348.01369517349
), `24` = c(20793.085494354, 8352.14257508482, 8602.54788558817, 
7648.16179856875, 734.461243165825, 9670.06409273764, 11224.9505551394, 
9172.19466958075, 8198.55046658255), `25` = c(22132.6475894638, 
8674.35610622285, 8699.50501762589, 7501.04650865343, 961.73046897726, 
10665.4475884693, 11843.4817070493, 9936.66848087776, 8229.66211057734
), `26` = c(23839.8860211177, 8602.53507774509, 8819.11134257235, 
7751.47383972585, 921.236485882212, 11398.1383831961, 12092.1087666409, 
10064.6809384318, 8098.57797994169), `27` = c(23746.1578026862, 
8560.48162960319, 8773.0067077387, 7854.99783916064, 895.10062740854, 
11381.2910837377, 12150.7862216127, 10195.9091054631, 8374.33411852265
), `28` = c(23569.7368512819, 8666.52365850174, 9131.31104785509, 
7774.3788124843, 1052.52385079171, 12246.6788512708, 12511.0051404575, 
10437.6067661719, 8197.79577760591), `29` = c(22456.6195157081, 
8461.2322343813, 9150.43364915247, 7966.66976248544, 1162.94639354954, 
12416.6597767858, 12153.7265342395, 10119.5157579639, 8169.13063023644
), `30` = c(21762.0342000136, 8831.58688676778, 9142.11869783641, 
8361.40591301217, 1171.72725552311, 12334.0298565943, 11693.4734863671, 
10386.9882591458, 7760.86031604133), `31` = c(20638.5119525099, 
8665.2088068053, 8821.70069557086, 7842.26528963175, 1021.12658495323, 
11831.6450072351, 11668.7539872729, 10007.3923036816, 8027.81771197702
), `32` = c(20549.4566456454, 8795.76970884077, 9109.9596987557, 
8057.71095034583, 999.023061095627, 11878.1823488474, 11893.8717926755, 
10079.7423664206, 8275.74272047015), `33` = c(19581.1660279597, 
8979.99993572275, 9706.01681511446, 8176.377249959, 983.394068365965, 
12077.5566539624, 11598.399644789, 10153.5024956492, 8408.91795875362
), `34` = c(19087.2054646927, 9486.22545610393, 9544.51091463266, 
8394.72381570239, 1108.71981201508, 12420.9712385115, 11982.1478563083, 
9922.11659378433, 8383.72826505381), `35` = c(18745.238739532, 
9812.04818003273, 10315.5335102931, 8808.79850459911, 986.454437581682, 
12297.4724586704, 11428.0000150509, 10610.2786565296, 8279.26728126007
), `36` = c(18277.4549847095, 10122.210470465, 10208.2359232298, 
8851.94060117528, 1111.36742898778, 12008.8413533203, 11242.5752706777, 
10236.9876532448, 8387.29327352296), `37` = c(17701.7646232022, 
10243.791353434, 10458.2264343781, 8845.11734460238, 1086.1799958845, 
11990.1171184789, 11138.180285971, 10183.7273950193, 8615.94308567703
), `38` = c(17071.9104982684, 10328.4507632513, 10388.0894917906, 
9181.66654148934, 1080.27220041016, 11409.6915951336, 11313.2550724198, 
10198.7376430536, 8462.82612606421), `39` = c(16173.371148947, 
9990.99674708065, 10286.7069198209, 9082.73603159613, 941.042940103086, 
11124.6124554133, 11027.7010291583, 9688.62694822957, 8608.62650274461
), `40` = c(16179.1097545585, 10185.5071281068, 10250.3111211468, 
9033.91537354837, 923.787160533988, 11373.8511126703, 11155.3374761727, 
9865.40533745142, 8425.406905904), `41` = c(15924.7339626463, 
10161.0162107055, 10509.4694366787, 9138.68228041329, 923.283649135943, 
11116.2878752842, 10676.7253706111, 9679.17524873996, 8822.91983138334
), `42` = c(15905.7202145677, 10095.7500697452, 10476.9389693623, 
9163.82963863092, 1109.02237339635, 10906.208682696, 11095.5897935369, 
9802.80593329468, 8483.84862558694), `43` = c(15391.8703579052, 
9867.71243736394, 10681.9523546141, 9305.52718367993, 1078.45858460642, 
10763.6432299477, 10392.0349661456, 9954.64639257086, 8640.33406429955
), `44` = c(15564.9112965923, 9803.34134078455, 11179.1937174719, 
9241.79924244455, 915.486063751453, 10641.2962565536, 11389.2977980404, 
9917.92094748219, 8937.78989840262), `45` = c(14906.2764896205, 
9985.58210020847, 10710.8522153918, 8994.91427213514, 1048.4309199843, 
10373.5083303268, 10900.2785313837, 9776.85080715431, 8531.52226942705
), `46` = c(15053.7675195395, 9788.16832805028, 10743.2817693018, 
9071.86821346805, 984.460295694199, 9928.39679286011, 10772.2228387355, 
9502.73575036983, 9158.47537407851), `47` = c(14833.5151287946, 
9359.11859656466, 10363.7742780479, 9319.41547797377, 1028.89252225921, 
10249.9848539432, 10936.5332618412, 9750.09837647337, 8056.73880698843
), `48` = c(14602.5625464686, 9301.64448752531, 10285.2728624475, 
8754.6624188126, 1003.54256154486, 10064.6119986261, 10377.0116320173, 
9396.31399116634, 8744.73705598079), `49` = c(14261.7308956592, 
9491.56914155365, 10482.5995753796, 8104.12404383856, 921.629277413151, 
9571.6124964415, 10327.1128191256, 9426.9045301672, 8610.7005684931
), `50` = c(14159.6582093318, 9239.3029268129, 9983.76228621509, 
8669.95513899805, 801.251104956904, 9608.68637762335, 10172.0025212776, 
9248.03829204374, 8531.71081407042), `51` = c(14108.8574624492, 
9297.03038105175, 10214.6357335876, 8066.13388422401, 928.322775849972, 
9385.58665633623, 9786.51641620935, 8694.12777739524, 8503.6498792477
)), .Names = c("DEPT", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
"23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", 
"34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", 
"45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51"), row.names = c("75", 
"77", "78", "91", "92", "921", "93", "94", "95"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That indeed seems odd. But this is not reproducible, please add `dput(Denom_2008_A)`

Comment: Ok, I've added `dput(Denom_2008_A)`. I use the `aggregate` function a lot and have never come across this before.

Comment: Cannot reproduce:  works fine for me.  You may want to clear out your userspace, or make sure that you've got the current version of `aggregate` loaded.

Comment: I also didn't get any error

Comment: Strange - I've just updated to the latest RStudio version, and tried with only `Denom_2008_A` in the global environment and I still get the same error.

Comment: Try reloading your dataset from the `dput` above, and run `getAnywhere(aggregate)` to make sure you're still calling `stats::aggregate` .

Comment: After the above procedure - the error is still the same! `summaryBy` also produces an error due to the length of `DEPT`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the names of my columns. The names of the columns cannot be a number. Changing the names of the columns allows me to `aggregate` as normal. Thanks for all the help.